# widget for function input is not shown in nbviewer

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've written a python module and would like to make some of the functions available via a jupyter notebook. For this I would like to visualise (plot) the functions. The notebook should be interactive, i.e. the user can change inputs and gets the corresponding result / plot back.

I've tried to make a use case work as I've never used jupyter before. I followed [this](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html). Here is the code from their site:

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(m, b):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    plt.plot(x, m * x + b)
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=(-2.0, 2.0), b=(-3, 3, 0.5))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

locally everything is working fine. As soon as I upload it to github and want to show it on nbviewer (can be found [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/canicola/test/blob/master/show%20case.ipynb)) the interactive sliders don't work. What am I doing wrong?

Is there a restriction for this on the python version?